# Calling elements of php array into jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am going to call the elements of the following array into jquery.

```
$options[] = array( 'title' => 'Upload Favicon',
                    'id'    => 'favicon',
                    'type'  => 'upload' );
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work..

```
jquery("'.$option['id'].'").hide();
```

May be I am wrong, but I myself guess that it is because in the jquery code there is no # for id calling, but I do not know how to add #.

Please help..

Comment: `jQuery("#'.$option['id'].'").hide();` I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem is here:

```
$options[] = array( 'title' => 'Upload Favicon',  
        ^^
```

This says "add an element to the array `$options`, and set that element's value to the array `'title' => 'Upload Favicon'...`. If `$option` is not yet set, it will be created as an array.  So it will effectively be like this:

```
$options = array (
    array ('title' => 'Upload Favicon',
           'id'    => 'favicon',
           'type'  => 'upload'
          );
);
```

This probably isn't what you mean, simnce you'll need to access it like this:

```
$options[0]['id']
```

To fix it, remove the `[]`:

```
$options = array( 'title' => 'Upload Favicon',
                  'id'    => 'favicon',
                  'type'  => 'upload' 
                );
```

Comment: What about the extremely vague `jquery("'.$option['id'].'").hide();` it has 2 errors on jQuery alone.

Comment: @Esailija That could easily be an extract of a coherent PHP statement, if you assume single quotes before and after the jQuery statement. I was presuming this is an extract of a longer statement.